# Need help getting started on Facebook C# API

Tags: c#, facebook, sdk

i'm trying to create a new facebook iframe application using asp.net and c#, and can't find any getting started guides. what i'm looking for is an extremely basic intro - i.e. what .dll files to put, what code to use to authorize and get userID, etc. Once i get the structure started i'll be able to figure everything out...but i can't make the basic connection to facebook!

a simple sample app would be extremely helpful.

thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Many people have tried to use the facebooktoolkit and failed miserably. Don't take my word for it, just look through the forum going back some months.  Adoption by Microsoft didn't add value to that project which IMO is going to die at some point from its own weight.

The SDK provided by Facebook was a hackathon project that was announced 6 months ago and doesn't seem to have been updated since. It's tough to imagine a company of Facebook's size and stature being so incompetent, but let's face it, they have a political bent which is Microsoft-adverse, so it's no wonder that they haven't  put any effort into helping this side of the world of development.

I helped a bit on another FBGraph.NET project which, while a noble effort, has been retired.  A search in Codeplex will reveal many such projects.

The project at http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/ is fairly new and doesn't have old baggage from prior .NET implementations.  For many reasons it seems to have a good start amidst the mass of failures out there.  This is the one I've just started using after evaluating the current list of offerings.  I recommend you take a look.  There's a sense of almost immediate gratification and (despite a lack of extensive docs for the time being) you might find yourself quickly getting  productive, which is the goal after all.  The software is being written in a way that removes the focus from the software (no heavy class library to implement every data type) and puts the focus back on the FB API itself, which is why I cruise here for solutions rather than in that project's forum.  That's kinda refreshing after working with the others.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/

or, more specifically, https://github.com/facebook/csharp-sdk

or, any of these other 3rd party provided ones: http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=facebook&ac=8

Comment: yes, i'm trying to use the Facebook C# SDK

Comment: @steve: I'd recommend you use any c# API but the one facebook put together.  That project looks like they haven't done anything with it for 6 months and there's been obvious changes.  try one of the other ones from codeplex.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,
http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

The Outercurve implementation is at:

http://csharpsdk.org