# Facebook Dummy application

Tags: c#, facebook

I want to create a duumy application in which the user which is logged in(facebook) see his own facebook friend list and their details like gender, status, wall post etc. on my own application using Graph API?.

Is it possible if Yes then please suggest me how is it?

thanks

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319671/need-help-getting-started-on-facebook-c-sharp-api to get started with the Facebook C# API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible through connecting your application with Facebook's API. Your question is pretty general so I would recommend that you start reading the documentation and then ask a more specific question if you run into any problems.

External links:

- [Facebook Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/)
- [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/)